# Find the locus of $z$ such that $\arg \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} = \alpha$: confused when $\alpha = 0$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the locus of $z$ such that $\arg \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} = \alpha$.
> Use and draw $w = \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}$.

This exercise was discussed many times -- [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120597/finding-the-loci-of-arg-dfracz-az-b-theta?rq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333930/reasoning-centre-and-ways-of-expressing-locus-of-arg-frac-z-az-b-c?rq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573659/how-to-describe-the-locus-of-z-where-arg-left-fracz-z-1z-z-2-right-t?rq=1), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844695/locus-of-complex-number-2/1844716#1844716) -- but I was unable to find answers to my problem with $0$ there.

I believe I understand where the arcs came from, here's my work:

[image: picture showing my work]

If I understand correctly, for $\alpha = \pm\pi$, the locus would be the segment connecting $z_2$ and $z_1$, not including the points themselves.

I can not understand what is happening when $\alpha = 0$.

$\alpha = 0 = \arg \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} = \arg w \Longrightarrow \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} = k \in \mathbb{R}, \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} = k\frac{z-z_2}{z-z_2}.$

Solving this for $z$, $z = \frac{x_1-kx_2}{1-k} +i\frac{y_1-ky_2}{1-k}$. I am having trouble understanding the locus of this $z$. The textbook says it should be 'two segments with end points in $z_1$ and $z_2$, and one of this segments contains an infinitely distant point'. How to understand why is this answer right, and how to draw it? It seems the infinitely distant point matches $k=1$, but why should it lie in the 'direction' of the line passing through $z_1$ and $z_2$?

My class notes are messy. Why is $(0, 1)$ special on $w$ plane?
[image: messy class notes]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that (within a modulus of $2\pi$), 
$\arg \left(w_1 \times w_2\right) ~=~ \arg(w_1) + \arg(w_2).$

Therefore, $\arg \left(\frac{w_1}{w_2}\right) ~=~ \arg(w_1) - \arg(w_2).$

> I can not understand what is happening when $\alpha = 0.$

In this situation, you have that

$$0 = \alpha ~=~ \arg \left(\frac{z - z_1}{z - z_2}\right)
~=~ \arg(z - z_1) - \arg(z - z_2).$$

Imagine the infinite line that passes through $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Note, that the $\arg$ function is not defined on the complex number $(0 + i[0]).$

Therefore, $z$ is not allowed to equal either $z_1$ or $z_2$.

There are 3 possibilities:

$\underline{\text{case 1} ~z ~\text{is not on this line}}$

Then,

$$\arg(z - z_1) \neq  \arg(z - z_2).$$

Therefore, this possibility must be excluded from the locus of satisfying points.

$\underline{\text{case 2} ~z ~\text{is on this line}, ~\textbf{but between}
~z_1 ~\text{and} ~z_2}$

Then,

$$\arg(z - z_1) ~=~  \arg(z - z_2) ~\pm ~\pi.$$

Therefore, this possibility must also be excluded from the locus of satisfying points.

$\underline{\text{case 3} ~z ~\text{is on this line}, ~\textbf{but not between}
~z_1 ~\text{and} ~z_2}$

Then, **regardless** of whether the point $z$ is closer to $z_1$ or closer to $z_2$,

$$\arg(z - z_1) ~=~  \arg(z - z_2).$$

Therefore, this possibility represents the locus of **all** satisfying points.

Thus, the locus of all satisfying points, when $\alpha = 0,$ is all $z$ that are
on the line formed by $z_1$ and $z_2$, but are **not** between $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and perspicuous explanation. I wanted to apologize that it took so long to accept the answer -- real life happened, and I forgot. Sorry. Thank you.

Comment: @user2661923 In case two I think it should be $\arg(z - z_1) ~-~  \arg(z - z_2) ~\pm ~\pi.$

Comment: @mathophile Your comment apparently has a typo, since your assertion contains no equal sign.  If you intend the assertion that $$\arg(z - z_1) - \arg(z - z_2) ~\color{red}{=}~ \pm \pi,$$ then your assertion is equivalent to my statement that $$\arg(z - z_1) = \arg(z - z_2) \pm \pi.$$  If this is not what you are asserting, please re-state your assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=x+iy;\;z_1=x_1+iy_1;\;z_2=x_2+iy_2$
$$\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}= \frac{x^2-x (x_1+x_2)+x_1 x_2+(y-y_1) (y-y_2)}{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}+i\frac{x (y_2-y_1)+x_1 (y-y_2)+x_2 (y_1-y)}{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}$$
$$\text{arg}\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=\arctan\frac{{\frac{x (y_2-y_1)+x_1 (y-y_2)+x_2 (y_1-y)}{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}}}{{\frac{x^2-x (x_1+x_2)+x_1 x_2+(y-y_1) (y-y_2)}{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}}}=\\=\arctan\frac{x (y_2-y_1)+x_1 (y-y_2)+x_2 (y_1-y)}{x^2-x (x_1+x_2)+x_1 x_2+(y-y_1) (y-y_2)}$$

$$\text{arg}\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0\to x (y_2-y_1)+x_1 (y-y_2)+x_2 (y_1-y)=0$$
Rearrange
$$x (y_2-y_1)+y (x_1-x_2)+x_2y_1-x_1y_2=0$$
which is the equation of a line.

In the general case, let $a=\cot\alpha$

$$x^2+y^2+x (-x_1-x_2+y_1 a -y_2 a )+y (-x_1 a +x_2 a -y_1-y_2)+x_1 x_2+x_1 y_2 a -x_2 y_1 a +y_1 y_2=0$$
$$x^2+y^2+px+qy+r=0$$
we get a circle.

Hope this can be useful.

Comment: I was going to answer the same